# $http.get succeeds; but can't access output?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, promise

How do I get the output from my remote server? - Firebug confirms that the JSON output is correct.

Here is my attempt, I have tried to be as standard as possible ([Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UNGeKSSgCGTUnxJuDns4)):

#### app.js, controllers.js, factories.js

```
'use strict';

var nameVersionFactory = angular.module('name.factories.version', []);

nameVersionFactory.factory('Version', ['$q', '$http', function ($q, $http) {
    var d = $q.defer();
    $http.get('/api').then(function (response) {
        d.resolve(response);
    });

    return d.promise;
}]);

var nameVerCtrl = angular.module('name.controllers.version',
                                 ['name.factories.version']);

nameVerCtrl.controller(
    'verCtrl', ['$scope', 'Version', function ($scope, Version) {
        $scope.version = Version;  /* {'status': 'online',
                                       'rest_api_version': '1.1.14',
                                       'server_time': '…'} */
    }]
);

var nameApp = angular.module('name', ['name.controllers.version']);

/* CORS */
nameApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}]);
```

Python REST API (30 lines): https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7d34867aca543911a06f

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app="name" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-ng-controller="verCtrl">
            <pre>{{version | json}}</pre>
            <pre>{{version.status}}</pre>
            <pre>{{version.data | json}}</pre>
            <pre>{{version.data.status}}</pre>
        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/factories.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Unfortunately I get no JSON output within those `<pre>…</pre>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Promises are no longer unwrapped automatically by scope variables in Angular 1.2+.

So, you have to do:

```
Version().then(function(result){
    $scope.version = result;    
});
```

Moreover, `$http` returns promises already, so this:

```
var d = $q.defer();
$http.get('/api').then(function (response) {
    d.resolve(response);
});

return d.promise;
```

Can simply become:

```
return $http.get("/api");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still isn't working. Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/UNGeKSSgCGTUnxJuDns4?p=preview

Comment: @AT your angular isn't bootstrapped correctly so your controller isn't run. Were you able to fix that since?

Comment: @AT in that case please consider accepting an answer or alternatively writing your own in order to help future viewers of this question.